# How Can I Show GIF Image In Custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Today, I faced a problem that the GIF images can't be displayed in a custom ListView. Should I use a third-party library to achieve it?
(I working with android studio)

Sample image: http://www.dongabank.com.vn/images/flag/AUD.gif

My code:

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(v == null){
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.image      = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFlag);
            viewHolder.type       = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewType);
            viewHolder.muatienmat = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewMua);
            viewHolder.bantienmat = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewBan);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);

        }
        Exchange ex = arrayExchange.get(position);
        if(ex != null){
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://www.dongabank.com.vn/images/flag/AUD.gif")
                    .into(viewHolder.image);
            viewHolder.type.setText(ex.getType());
            viewHolder.muatienmat.setText(ex.getMuatienmat());
            viewHolder.bantienmat.setText(ex.getBantienmat());

        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Glide instead of Picasso.

It's almost same as Picasso.And it supports gif.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
 Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://www.dongabank.com.vn/images/flag/AUD.gif")
                    .asGif().into(viewHolder.image);
```

Comment: I have tried with Glide but same result as Picasso.

Comment: To be honest, I use Glide and it works to play gif. But it's loading time is so slow

Answer (score 1):

This is a native library: https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

It`s save my life a lot of time.